# SSHD skips PAM auth

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam

I developed a PAM module for authentication and I want SSH to use it. I put it on the top of the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` stack, but it is not called. I know for sure that the module works because I integrated it in the login.

How do I have to set the /etc/ssh/sshd_config in order to use it?

Edit: UsePAM is already set to yes, tried also all the possible combination of `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and `PasswordAuthentication` `yes` and `no` values.

Answer (score 1):

That was mine mistake: The module was actually called, but it was trying to read a line from the console. While this works in login, it can't in SSH. 
The correct way to do that is to use

```
const char *username = NULL;
const char *password = NULL;

pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_USER, (const void **)&username);
pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, (const void **)&password);
```

This will set `username` and `password` with the values retrieved by SSH.
In order to get the password, set `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and in `etc/pam.d/sshd` replace `@include common-auth` with `auth required your-module`